# How to get a value from HTML5 color picker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the color of an h1 element based on a selection using the color input type, but i cant seem to get it to work. I've tried outputting the color variable to an alert and it only returns undefined.

```
 $(function(){

        $("#changeColor").click(function(){

          var color =  $("#colorChoice").value

          $("h1").css("color" + '"' + color + "'")


        });



    });


    </script>


</head>
  <html>
  <body>

  <h1>This is the default text</h1>
  <form>
  <fieldset>
      <select id="changeFont">
        <option>Arial</option>
        <option>Georgia</option>
        <option>Helevtica</option>
    </select>
    <input type="color" id="colorChoice">
    <button id="changeColor" class="btn-primary pull-right">Change</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `var color =  $("#colorChoice").val();` See [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

You might as well bind your callback on the onChange event instead of the onClick event:

```
$("#colorChoice").change(function(){
  $("h1").css('background', $(this).val());
});
```

[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/mv6We/2/)

Comment: This is a great way of handling it.  I hadn't even though of using on change as en event listener.  Good stuff!

Answer (score 8):

Don't use Jquery for this. vanillaJS works just fine

```
document.getElementById("colorChoice").value;
```

Answer (score 7):

Your syntax is incorrect.

JavaScript:

```
var color = document.getElementById("colorChoice").value;
```

jQuery:

```
var color =  $("#colorChoice").val();
```

I recommend using vanilla JS as it is faster than jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Try this using vanilla JavaScript.

```
function changeColor(){
    document.getElementById("colorChoice").addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        let color = e.target.value;
        document.getElementById('bgColor').style.backgroundColor = color; 
    });
};

changeColor();
```

Don't forget to add those ids to your HTML.
In my case, I'm using #bgColor for the div and #colorChoice for the color picket input.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
document.getElementById("colorChoice").addEventListener('change', (e) => {

color = e.target.value;

})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify the value attribute of the color input type tag it will not grab the color using javascript

First: Keep the value attribute with any color hex value.

```
<input type="color" value="#858585" id="colorChoice">
```

Second: Use jQuery property value. for example,

```
$('#colorChoice').on('change', function() {
    var newbgcolor = this.value;
    $('#playground').css('background', newbgcolor);
});
```